# How to set unlimited scrolling on a TTY?

Tags: tty, scrolling

On  a TTY ( <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd> to <kbd>f6</kbd> ), I use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>page up</kbd> to scroll up and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>page down</kbd> to scroll down. But the problem is, the scrolling is limited to certain number of lines.

How can I get unlimited scrolling on a TTY ?

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/346018/how-to-increase-the-scrollback-buffer-size-for-tty

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, you buy unlimited memory.
Take a look at the kernel paramter `fbcon=scrollback:Nk` where N is the desired buffer size is kilobytes.  The default is 32k, so increase it from there.

To increase framebuffer console memory :

```
gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Now edit and change `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="fbcon=scrollback:<value>k"` .

Now, update grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

And restart your computer

Comment: This seems to be a working answer :P , but I don't know where to find kernel parameters and how to edit them. Could you please add some more explanation ?  Thanks :)

Comment: You might be able to improve this answer with providing the steps needed in more detail to make it a rock solid answer.

Comment: Digging deeper, I got this : https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/fb/fbcon.txt , And Yes you are right! :D . Its given "`fbcon=scrollback:<value>[k]`

        The scrollback buffer is memory that is used to preserve display
        contents that has already scrolled past your view.  This is accessed
        by using the Shift-PageUp key combination.  The value 'value' is any
        integer. It defaults to 32KB.  The 'k' suffix is optional, and will
        multiply the 'value' by 1024." 

***But I still don't know how to edit them :P*** .

Comment: Is there a way of doing this without restarting? (say you're using a live image?)

Comment: I don't see fbcon in the sysctl -a output, so probably not.